# The chart doesn't show up on the data app - Shapelets Platform

Tags: python, pandas, function, selector, altair

I have been trying to work on Shapelets Dataapp to display information for a presentation. I tried to work on a selector that would display the data depending on the zip code. Everything is working but when I use it nothing is displaying, can someone help me?

here is my code:

```
import shapelets as sh
import pandas as pd
from shapelets.apps import  AltairChart, DataApp
app = DataApp(name= "Test")
import altair as alt

cat= pd.read_csv("/root/Papa_johns/papa_person.csv")

def full_bar(cat: dict, selector: str) -> AltairChart:
    cat = cat[selector]
    melted_cat = pd.melt(cat.reset_index(), id_vars=['postalCode'], var_name='Feature', value_name='Count')

    # create stacked bar chart
    chart = alt.Chart(melted_cat).mark_bar().encode(
        x='postalCode:N',
        y='Count:Q',
        color='Feature:N',
        tooltip=['postalCode:N', 'Feature:N', 'Count:Q']
    ).properties(width=600, height=400, title=f'Bar Chart by Zipcode and {selector}').interactive()

    return app.altair_chart(chart=chart)

selector = app.selector(title="Select the Postal Code", options = ['33122','33125','33126','33127','33128','33129','33130','33131','33132','33133','33134','33135','33136','33137','33138','33139','33140','33141','33142','33143','33144','33145','33146','33147','33148','33149','33150','33151','33152','33153','33155','33156','33157','33161','33162','33165','33166','33167','33168','33169','33170','33172','33173','33174','33175','33176','33177','33178','33179','33180','33181','33182','33183','33184','33185','33186','33187','33188','33189','33190','33193','33194'])
app.place(selector)
text= app.text("choose your zipcode")

selector.bind(text, full_bar)

app.register()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw what was your problem. The way to bind two functions is to use the label or text, then bind with all the elements in it (function, Data, widget). In your case you inverted the display of the elements, you did a selector, and then included the text. it will work if you would have done

```
text.bind(cat, full_bar, selector)
```

I hope it helped you and you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo